# Compilling GodotGooglePlayBilling 1.1.2 for Google billing library Version 4 for Godot

Tags: in-app-billing, godot, android-billing

From what I have been able to investigate I need version 1.1.2 of the GodotGooglePlayBilling.1.1.2.release.aar file to be able to use version 4 of the google payments library, but in the official GitHub version there is only GodotGooglePlayBilling.1.0.1.release.aar.

How can I compile this version?

Answer (score -1):

The answer might be found here:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot-google-play-billing/releases/tag/2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).